# Which mounting bracket to use with a geared box?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, motors

Which **90 degree bracket** would you use for this one? Do you have any suggestions for what i should be looking for, I find it very hard to find something. It is 5cm between all the outer holes.
[image]
Would love to use **something like this**, but that doesn't works for my uneven, off-centre, geared dc motor. 
[image]

Comment: Then get one made or contact the unit supplier as they may provide brackets or not...

Comment: If i can't find then I'll end up creating my own

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't find anything so i recommend you creating a custom bracket. Created this one instead[image]

Comment: Plus1 for effort.